# Reading Mp3 File using NAudio.dll on windows server 2008 r2 when media player is not installed

Tags: c#-4.0, mp3, desktop-application, windows-server-2008-r2, naudio

I am reading the length of mp3 files using NAdutio.dll. the code sample i used is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net). the application i have created is a stand alone desktop application built in C# 4.0 and is used on the network of computers all with windows server 2008 operating systems. and there is no media player installed on any of those computer. when i run the application on my local machine it return the length of mp3 files correctly, but when it is run on any pc on that network it return zero for every file. it seems that the NAudio.dll itself use the wmp.dll to read the audio. but i can not get install the media player or can not place the dll in each of those computers. is there any way that i can fix this dll problem by some work arround in the installer or code? any one please help me.

---

Thanks in Advance

Comment: NAudio does not use WMP, it uses the ACM MP3 decoder. To get this on Windows Server 2008 you need to install the "desktop experience" Windows component. Or you'll need to use fully managed MP3 decoder such as the one ioctlLR has recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try [NLayer](https://github.com/naudio/NLayer) to read the file.  The latest version's MpegFile implementation should provide you with length information nicely.  Just read the .Length and divide by .Channels * 4 (.Length is is bytes, and samples are in 32-bit float format).

**Please Note**: I've put a lot of work into this library, so while I'm not the maintainer, it is one of my projects.

Comment: How much i have to wait for this release?

Comment: There's not one currently, and I don't know when Mark is going to do one.  Your best bet is to just pull down the source code and build it yourself.

Comment: yes, code is stable at the moment, so just build from source. Will try to do a release later this year, but lots going on at the moment, so no time for working on NLayer