# NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest on Azure

Tags: azure, mp3, naudio

I am Using NAudio for getting MP3 file information as well merging 2 or more MP3 files. It works fine on localhost but when I publish the site on AZURE it throws error "NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to use something that is not installed on the machine in Azure - in your case it is ACM MP3 decoder. On a client Windows it can be pre-installed, but i do not think that server Windows can have it. 
Also i suspect that something like that will not be allowed to run on Azure Web Apps (it looks like you are trying to use that).

So, i would suggest you to use Virtual Machine for that and install needed components here or use something software-based. I have found:

```
new Mp3FileReader(stream,wave=> new DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wave))
```

It looks like it can be used in your case. Could you please try?

Comment: I tried this. Now the error is changed. Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BBEEA841-0A63-4F52-A7AB-A9B3A84ED38A} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). I ensure that My site is running on 32-bit on Azure

Comment: Hi, yes, it is good that you ensured that it is running on 32-bit web site, but it looks like there are no needed components on Azure Web Apps. I believe, for that, you should execute the steps described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221294/naudio-in-windows-azure-windows-server-2008-r2?rq=1 . The problem is that the Azure Web Apps "  management surface" is not very broad. Can you assess the migration the Cloud Services where you can execute the startup tasks and install needed components or even Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 0):

As Alex has said, it is because the MP3 codecs (both ACM and DMO) are not present on the server. Your options are to find a way to install them, or to use a fully managed MP3 decoder such as [NLayer](http://nlayer.codeplex.com/) instead.