# Using NAudio/Nlayer to mix two mp3 files

Tags: mp3, naudio, file-conversion

In reference to this question: [NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713713/nodriver-calling-acmformatsuggest-on-azure/44769231?noredirect=1#comment76519525_44769231)

My hosting server does not allow me to install anything or register dlls. I am using Naudio to mix to mp3 files and it gave me the error NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest.

I downloaded and installed Nlayer in my application and modified the code to look like this:

```
var builderBackground = new Mp3FileReader.FrameDecompressorBuilder(wf => new Mp3FrameDecompressor(wf)); 
var builderMessage = new Mp3FileReader.FrameDecompressorBuilder(wf => new Mp3FrameDecompressor(wf)); 
Mp3FileReader mpbacground = new Mp3FileReader(ThumbAudioMP3, builderBackground); Mp3FileReader mpMessage = new Mp3FileReader(stream, builderMessage); 
background = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mpbacground); 
message = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mpMessage);

var mixer = new WaveMixerStream32(); var messageOffsetted = new WaveOffsetStream(message, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
```

I get the same `NoDriver` calling acmFormatSuggest error in the line `WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(...`

Can someone tell me how I should be doing this? Any documentation on Nlayer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream` lines. The `Mp3FileReader` classes will already emit PCM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not sure I follow. The following code works but not in the server:
Mp3FileReader mpbacground = new Mp3FileReader(ThumbAudioMP3, wave => new DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wave));
                    Mp3FileReader mpMessage2 = new Mp3FileReader(stream, wave => new DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wave));
var mixer = new WaveMixerStream32();
var backgroundOffsetted = new WaveOffsetStream(mpbacground, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

Using the NLayer Decompressor I get an error in WaveOffsetStream: Only PCM supported

Comment: Perhaps you can give me a code sample or point me in the right direction? I'm stock with this issue not being able to mix the mp3 files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution. Media Foundation is also not installed in the server. All I need to do is to take two Mp3 files and merge them together. Is there a way to do this using the NLayer compresor? Can you provide me with a code sample? I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: I got one step further with this code: 
`code`
var builderMessage = new Mp3FileReader.FrameDecompressorBuilder(wf => new Mp3FrameDecompressor(wf));
Mp3FileReader mpbacground = new Mp3FileReader(ThumbAudioMP3, builderMessage);
Mp3FileReader mpMessage = new Mp3FileReader(stream, builderMessage);
var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(mpbacground.WaveFormat);
mixer.AddMixerInput(mpbacground);
mixer.AddMixerInput(mpMessage);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(fullPath, mixer);`code`

But now how do I trim the files to 60 seconds and resample them? How can I use WdlResamplingSampleProvider?